# When I use the "@" of the webpack alias in the Linux system to execute "npm run build"

Tags: linux, webpack, gitlab-ci-runner

When I use the "@" of the webpack alias in the Linux system to execute "npm run build".

the same

```
import LevelRadar from '@/common/component/echarts/radar/levelradar';
import CommonTimeLine from '@/common/component/commonTimeLine/commonTimeLine';
import FullScreen from '@/common/component/fullScreen/fullScreen';
import AnalysisHeader from '@/common/component/analysisHeader/analysisHeader';
import NoContent from '@/common/component/nocontent/nocontent';
```

```
**webpack**
const path = require('path');
const DIST_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist');
const moduleRules = require('./module/moduleRules');
const modulePlugins = require('./module/modulePlugins');
const moduleOptimization = require('./module/moduleOptimization');
let entry = [];

module.exports = {

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src')
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant gitlab.yml code and demo

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to write the error code！

```
ERROR in ./src/common/component/componetEntrance.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/common/component/echarts/radar/levelradar' in '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/WefvG_t8/0/develope/zhzg/sc/zhzg_yy_fxxt/code/web/zhzg-sc-analysis/src/common/component'
 @ ./src/common/component/componetEntrance.js 68:18-72
 @ ./src/container/organization/intelligentAnalysisView/IndexComponent.js
 @ ./src/router/policeVersion/PoliceVersionRouter.js
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
```